# Blender shows this error 'Loading 'C:\file.blend': Missing DNA block;

Tags: rendering

I tried to open my file in blender after restarting my pc and it showed this error.please help

Answer (score -1):

> More often than not if the Missing DNA Block message appears the affected *.blend file will be utterly unusable, nothing can be done to retrieve the user generated content it otherwise contained. In these instances it may still be possible to reestablish the project checking whether Blender created a *.blend1 backup file in the project folder ...

Read on at https://www.katsbits.com/codex/missing-dna-block/